# @property as method for external wraping/decorating

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, properties

I have a property i would like to decorate but i only want do decorate it if the active file is the main file (__main__). I have tried to handle it as a instance method but it doesn't work since a property does not have a callable state (as i know of). This is what i have tried:

```py
def timer(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        dt1 = time()
        out = func(*args,**kwargs)
        print(func.__qualname__,'ran for',time()-dt1,'seconds\n')
        return out
    return wrapper

class mainclass():
    def __init__(self,data): self.data = data

    @property
    def asArr(self): return list(self.data)

mainclass.asArr = timer(mainclass.asArr)
```

Is there a way to get it as a first class function and then after catching it can i convert it back to a property linked to the class to be used by any instances? Any alternate solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Please post an example that we could actually test. What you have now isn't even syntactically valid, as `class` is a keyword.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "i only want do decorate it if the active file is the main file", please?